# How to color a range of cells in a row in a table?

Tags: tables, color, multirow, colortbl, rowcolor

In the below code I have tried to redefine the `\cellcolor` command to achieve the effect of coloring a range of consecutive cells in a row by creating a command called `\colorrow`. It didn't work out.
I have also shown that we can use the `\rowcolor` command for the task; however, it throws an error while compiling.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{yellow}{RGB}{255, 204, 50}
\definecolor{yellow2}{RGB}{255, 238, 150}

\newcommand{\colorrow}[2]{%
  % Define a temporary command \do
  \gdef\do##1{\cellcolor{#2}##1\ignorespaces}%
  % Expand \do with the content of the first argument
  \expandafter\do#1\unskip%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
   \multirow{2}{*}{Model}  & \colorrow{18 & 0.748 & 0.143}{yellow} \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow2} 18 & 0.748 & 0.143 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The`\rowcolor` does the job but throws following error

"You have used a \hline command in the wrong place, probably outside a table. If the \hline command is written inside a table, try including \ before it.
 \noalign

l.20      & \rowcolor
{yellow2} 18 & 0.748 & 0.143 \
I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.

[1

"
[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `tabularray` package. It makes it really simple to colour parts of your table.

Comment: `\rowcolor` has to be used at the start of a row.  Just use `\cellcolor` in each cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [tabularray](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package can be used.

The options are set with keys. For example, `cell{1}{2}={bg=myyellow}` sets a background with color `myyellow`. Similarly, `cell{2}{2-Z}={bg=myyellow2}` sets a background with color `myyellow2` for the cells in the second row from the second column till the last column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{255, 204, 50}
\definecolor{myyellow2}{RGB}{255, 238, 150}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  hlines,
  vlines,
  cell{1}{2}={bg=myyellow},
  cell{2}{2-Z}={bg=myyellow2}
}
\SetCell[r=2]{m} Model & 18 & 0.748 & 0.143\\
 & 18 & 0.748 & 0.143\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```